# re.split('[+ -]',f) or better stepping to partial derivatives

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been running in circles on some basic stuff. My idea is the following: I want to write a simple def , to do partial derivatives. I know there are tools out there already, but I happen to be an egotist with presumably bad antiquated python skills. without further ado, here is the situation. 
   First the strategy: 
       I want to split something like  2x + 3y into [2x , 3y]; then act on 2x , thus [0] and 3y, [1]  with a derivative operation which I have not written yet. I plan on doing this symbolically. I have decided not to look into too much detail on how others have done it without trying a few dirty attempts.
     Here is my non working implentation

```
def partialderivative(f, a):

 import re
 L = list(f)
 re.split('[+ -]', L)
 derivative (L[0],x)
 derivative (L[0],y)
 derivative (L[1],x)
 derivative (L[1],y)
```

print(some results)

Now there are many things going on that I don't fully understand. If I run the first part above via command line carefully ensuring that f --> 'f' and 
proceeding as 
     re.split('[+ -]',f) ,
then I will have it split, but that is about it
The part below the " ------------------ " is more or less pseudo code.

This is probably going to be the dumbest question posted here. . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`re.split()` just accept string type so you couldn't pass a list to it . also in your pattern you have a space that is extra you need `r'[+-]'` :

```
>>> s="2x + 3y"
>>> s1="2x + 3y"
>>> s2="2x - 3y"
>>> re.split(r'[+-]',s1)
['2x ', ' 3y']
>>> re.split(r'[+-]',s2)
['2x ', ' 3y']
```

also you can remove spaces from your splited elements with `str.strip` :

```
>>> [i.strip() for i in re.split(r'[+-]',s2)]
['2x', '3y']
```

And within a function :

```
>>> def spliter(s):
...    return [i.strip() for i in re.split(r'[+-]',s)]
... 
>>> spliter(s1)
['2x', '3y']
>>> s3="4x + 12z - 18k"
>>> spliter(s3)
['4x', '12z', '18k']
```

Comment: sounds good. Let me run it in command line, then see  if I can module it up somehow

Comment: It works fin in command line as I would expect. When I try to run it in module a few things go wrong.   When I put in  2x+3y for s, I get an error.

Comment: I get invalid syntax  when I put it exactly as show above. When I put it in as "2x+3y", with the quotes, I get "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#68>", line 1, in <module>
    cow.spliter("2x+3y")
  File "C:\Python34\cow.py", line 54, in spliter
    return [i.strip() for i in re.split(r'[+-]',s)]
NameError: name 're' is not defined"  .  Do I need to predefine s somewhere in the module?  My hope is for it to take a generic function and split it.    This is what I put in exactly as "def spliter(s):

Comment: @kevinTahN. you didnt import `re` , just add `import re` at the top level of your module

Comment: return [i.strip() for i in re.split(r'[+-]',s)] " . I do "import cow" , then cow.spliter(2x+3y) , out of desperation, I tried, cow.spliter("2x+3y"). It seems a rather trivial thing, but I am not even sure what to do any more lol

Comment: In had to post in chunks because of the length restrictions, but the comment series captures the shortcommings

Comment: @kevinTahN. as is say you have `NameError: name 're' is not ` so you just need to import `re`